# AngularJS how to return a promise from a ng-include directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a view with an ng-include directive.
The value is bound to a model.

```
<div ng-app="mainModule">
    <div id="mainController" ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <div ng-include="main.guestUrl"></div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

The model can be changed outside of the controller with plain javascript.

```
var promise = angular.element(controller).controller().navigateTo("controller/view");
```

Then in my controller I set the model.

```
    vm.goTo = function (url) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            vm.guestUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        });            
    };

I can use the includeContentRequested event, but how do I return the promise ?

    $scope.$on('includeContentRequested', function (e) {

    });
```

Now I'm not using ng-include, but doing the $http request and the $compile myself, so I can return a promise.

```
vm.navigateTo = function (url) {          

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    });

    promise.then(function successCallback(response) {
        var container = $('#mainContainer');
        container.empty();

        var html = response.data;

        container.append(html);

        $compile(container)($scope);

        deferred.resolve('ok');

    }, function errorCallback(reason) {
        deferred.reject(reason);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I think it's cleaner to use a ng-include directive.

Does anyone know how to return a promise in the includeContentRequested event ?

I come up with this code to be possible to notify the host, but it's ugly.
So I think I rest with my $http call.

```
vm.goTo = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        vm.guestUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://localhost:63661/');
    });

    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function (args) {
        deferred.resolve('ok');
        $scope.$destroy('$includeContentLoaded');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Sure seems like a long way around creating your own simple directive without needing to use jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl this is because it's called from another project that doesn't have AngularJS included

Comment: But if you are entering the angular app could simply use an angular event to update a directive

Comment: What are actually you trying to do? Cos it is only event fired when content is requested. I don't think you are supposed to return anything in listener.

Comment: I'm trying to notice the caller, the view is loaded, why  you're always downvoating. I have a solution when I use the $http call, to load the view.
But I was wondering if there was a solution with ng-include, to notice the caller, the view is loaded

Comment: There is solution. Just use '$includeContentLoaded'. NgInclude emits more than one event and none of the listener are supposed to return anything. btw. I did not down vote you, but your question is very confusing.

Comment: @sielakos, I'll try one more time, I know it is confusing, and I understand my question is not clear. But this is the case. I have a project that is acting like a host, without AngularJS. This host is calling another project,  that is acting like a guest and works with AngularJS. The host loads views from the guest, but this guest has also templates, that is loading with ng-includes. And the host has to know when those templates are loaded. So the guest has to notify the host. How to accomplish this ?

Comment: When content is included using ng-include '$includeContentLoaded' event is fired. Just use it. See source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L257

Answer (score 1):

instead of using ng-include - I would suggest using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives) which has its own controller and scope.
this scope is a great place to put a promise (which is an abstraction built on top of a variable)

Comment: This would be indeed an idea. I will try this suggestion. thx